# Iterating over a DataFrame, evaluating column values, and setting value to a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterable

I have been trying to iterate through a DataFrame or Apply a function, in order to change the content in a specific column of the DataFrame based on 2 other columns also in the DataFrame.

I have a df like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age_type' : pd.Series(['Adult','Adult','Child','Child']),
     'Gender' : pd.Series(['Female','Male','Female','Female'])
     })

   Gender  Age_type  Group
0  Female  Adult
1  Male    Adult
2  Female  Child
3  Female  Child
```

And I want to set a group for each case, with this idea:

```
if gender == 'Female' and age_type == 'Adult': 
   group = 'Group A'
elif gender == 'Female' and age_type == 'Child':
   group = 'Group B'
elif gender == 'Male' and age_type == 'Adult':
   group = 'Group C'
elif gender == 'Male' and age_type == 'Child':
   group = 'Group D'
```

I have tried to use .apply(function) because as far as I understand, you should never modify a DataFrame while iterating over it (So this would make a for loop not an option ¿?).

I have tried:

```
def set_group(data):
    gender = data['Gender']
    age_type = data['Age_type']
    if gender == 'Female' and age_type == 'Adult': 
       data['Group'] = 'Group A'
    elif gender == 'Female' and age_type == 'Child':
       data['Group'] = 'Group B'
    elif gender == 'Male' and age_type == 'Adult':
       data['Group'] = 'Group C'
    elif gender == 'Male' and age_type == 'Child':
       data['Group'] = 'Group D'
    return None

df['Group'].apply(set_group)
```

but I keep getting errors like: 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Any idea on how to iterate over a DataFrame, read some columns, and based on that, set the value for another column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dfx['group'] = ""
dfx['group'] = np.where((dfx['Gender']=='Female')&(dfx['Age_type']=='Adult'),'A', dfx['group'])
dfx['group'] = np.where((dfx['Gender']=='Female')&(dfx['Age_type']=='Child'),'B', dfx['group'])
dfx['group'] = np.where((dfx['Gender']=='Male')&(dfx['Age_type']=='Adult'),'C', dfx['group'])
dfx['group'] = np.where((dfx['Gender']=='Male')&(dfx['Age_type']=='Child'),'D', dfx['group'])
```

Comment: This works, so if there is a down vote, please explain.

Comment: This worked perfectly (just with a small adjustment in capital letters) . Thanks! @ivan7707

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
  Age_type  Gender
0    Adult  Female
1    Adult    Male
2    Child  Female
3    Child  Female

In [97]: m = {'FemaleAdult': 'Group A',
    ...:  'FemaleChild': 'Group B',
    ...:  'MaleAdult': 'Group C',
    ...:  'MaleChild': 'Group D'}

In [98]: df['group'] = (df.Gender + df.Age_type).map(m)

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
  Age_type  Gender    group
0    Adult  Female  Group A
1    Adult    Male  Group C
2    Child  Female  Group B
3    Child  Female  Group B
```

Comment: @RodolfoOrozco, glad it helps :)